# Adding specific shortcuts to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add in android studio same 3 shortcuts i use in Google Chrome:

ctrl + tab -> go to next tab

ctrl + shift + tab -> go to previous tab

ctrl + w -> delete current tab

I want to do same in android studio when i have opened for example 8 classes so I can navigate easily and optimize my coding time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File > Settings > Keymap :

go to Main menu > Window> Editor Tabs:

set your shortcuts for these :

**Select next tab**

**Select previous tab**

**close**

if you want to add **TAB, ESC and ENTER** in your shortcut select `+` icon in shortcut window.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I can't add any shortcut that contains "tab" in it. when I click for example ctrl + tab it goes in next line. It doesn't write it down as action

Comment: you can add TAB, ESC and Enter by pressing + icon in shortcut window and don't forget to remove previous shortcut.

Comment: hey guys...there is a shortcut that I used in java alot. Ctrl+Alt+F to make a variable a global vairable. It does not work in kotlin how do I create it.